# Callback of Ajax request using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jsp

Edited JS file :

Style 1:

```
$(document).ready(function() {<br>
$("#rootFolder").change(function(){<br>
var rootFolderValue = $('#rootFolder').val();<br>
//alert (rootFolderValue);<br>
$.getJSON("getSubfolder.jsp", { foldername: rootFolderValue }, function(json) {<br>

$.each(json, function(i, option) {<br>

$('#subFolder1').append($('').val(option.Value).html(option.Text));<br>
});<br>
});<br>
});<br>

});<br>
<br>
```

Style 2

```
$(document).ready(function() {<br>
$("#rootFolder").change(function(){<br>
var rootFolderValue = $('#rootFolder').val();<br>
alert (rootFolderValue);<br>
$.ajax({<br>
<br>
url: 'sample.jsp',<br>
data:'foldername='+rootFolderValue,<br>
dataType: "json",<br>
success:function(data){<br>
    $.each(data , function (key , value) {<br>
        $('#subFolder').append('<option value="'+key+'">"'+value+'"</option>');<br>
     });<br>
}<br>
});<br>
});<br>
});<br>
```

getSubfolder.jsp file

```
<%<br>
    String root = request.getParameter("foldername");<br>
    System.out.println("the value is "+root);<br>
    JSONObject arrayObj=new JSONObject();<br>
    String path = "G:\\Demo\\"+root;<br>
    File rootFile = new File(path);<br>
    File[] listOfDirs = rootFile.listFiles();<br>
     for (int i = 0; i < listOfDirs.length; i++)<br>
    {        <br>
    if (listOfDirs[i].isDirectory())<br>
    {<br>
       arrayObj.put(i,listOfDirs[i].getName().toString());<br>

    }<br>
    }<br>
    out.println(arrayObj);<br>
%><br>
```

Problem:
1) My arrayObj has values {"0":"A","1":"B"}  . But the dropdown is still not changing. Please help.. i have tried both methods mentioned below to change the dropdown.. Just stuck with it all day :)

Comment: What happens when you attach an event handler to the error call back? error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){alert(textStatus);}

Comment: Have you checked the output of `getSubfolder.jsp`? Try accessing the file directly first. You should record the output in your question.

Answer (score 1):

since `datatype` is `json`, the `each function` will return `key` and `value` as `params`, that you can use as below. You can use the value and key as per your requirement in `option` tag

```
success:function(data){
    $.each(data , function (key , value) {
        $('#subFolder').append('<option value="'+key+'">"'+value+'"</option>');
     });
}
```

Comment: I have edited my above question with rectifications given by you, but it still isnt working.Please help.

Comment: you are calling sample.jsp in ajax, try changing that and also try changing out.println(arrayObj); to out.println(arrayObj.toString);

Comment: Yah I changed it, but it still isnt working. My HTML in index.jsp is just  <SELECT NAME="subFolder1" ID="subFolder1"><br>
            <OPTION VALUE="">Choose a Folder...</OPTION><br>
        </SELECT><br>.  Still not getting the values?

Comment: you have mentioned id as "subFolder" in ajax but here it is "subFolder1"

Comment: yah as i wrote that, i rectified it as well :) . But it still aint working . Thanks for your quick responses. But I m just stuck with it .

Comment: np.. you put an alert(data) inside success function and check if you are getting the json data. also instead of out.println(arrayObj); try using <%= arrayObj%> outside the <% ... %>.

Comment: Yah, alert(data) isnt showing anything, also tried to alert some text like alert('hello'), no result. Then i edited the out.println to  <%=arrayObj%> ... which is still not working.

Comment: that means you are not getting the correct response..are you getting the that System.out.println as correct output ????

Comment: yah i m getting the value which is sent from the js file i.e root.

Comment: then there is problem in your response put another sysout with json object at last and check if the response object is correct.

Comment: Something weird . I just added two lines out.println(arrayObj.toString());<br>
     System.out.println(arrayObj.toString());<br> . Then the second dropdown on the basis of the first dropdown did change, but only for once, on again changing the first down, it showed the previous result. But how did System.out.print work?

Answer (score 0):

When you define the `datatype` as JSON, you need to make sure you are rendering JSON. I am unsure whether simply using `out.println` will do this.

Assuming it does output properly formatted [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), which would look something like

```
["option1", "option2", ... ] // or
[{"Value":"val1","Text":"text1"}, { ... }, ...]
```

You can use the following jQuery shortcut to both request the data via AJAX and parse the JSON. It is a no-nonsense clean solution that uses the API well!

```
$.getJSON("getsubfolder.jsp", { foldername: rootFolderValue }, function(json) {

  $.each(json, function(i, option) {

    $('#subFolder').append($('<option />').val(option.Value).html(option.Text));

  });

});
```

Comment: I have edited my above question with rectifications given by you, but it still isnt working.Please help.